# JavaFx : display an icon inside a table cell

Tags: javafx

I have the following table column cell specified :

```java
public class TableCellWithImage<T> extends TableCell<T, String> {
    private final ImageView image;

    public TableCellWithImage() {
        // add ImageView as graphic to display it in addition
        // to the text in the cell
        image = new ImageView( new Image( getClass().getResourceAsStream("/eyes.png")));
        image.setFitWidth(24);
        image.setFitHeight(24);
        image.setPreserveRatio(true);

        setGraphic(image);
        setMinHeight(70);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            // set back to look of empty cell
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item);
            setGraphic(image);
        }
    }
}
```

To apply it I use

```
content_column_.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<DbEntry, String>, TableCell<DbEntry, String>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<DbEntry, String> call(TableColumn<DbEntry, String> param) {
        return new TableCellWithImage<>();
    }
});
```

How to align graphic image and text inside the cell? I want an image to be placed in the right corner and be visible only in case of mouse hover.

Comment: Could you please give me a snippet how to customize a cell?

Comment: that's off scope for this site - there are enough tutorials out in the wild .. work through one and when stuck come back with a [mcve] ..

Comment: Ok, got a step forward for my problem. Now I got an image and text. How to set it's alignment?

Comment: face-value question is: what do you mean (beyond the java doc of Labeled ;) But then this wouldn't solve the requirement: learn how to attach listeners to the cell (same as with every node) or how to use build-in css support (you want hover, if I understand you correctly)

Comment: I see that by default, there is an image and then a text in a cell. What I want to have - text centered in the cell and image displayed at the right corner.

Comment: @kleopatra I achieved the alignment by setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT); Everything is fine right now. Thanks for pointing me the right direction, I'm quite new to JavaFx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a final solution to make a trick.

```
public class TableCellWithImage<T> extends TableCell<T, String> {
    private final ImageView image;
    BooleanProperty is_image_visible_ = new SimpleBooleanProperty( false );

    public TableCellWithImage() {
        // add ImageView as graphic to display it in addition
        // to the text in the cell
        image = new ImageView( new Image( getClass().getResourceAsStream("/eyes.png")));
        image.setFitWidth(24);
        image.setFitHeight(24);
        image.setPreserveRatio(true);

        setGraphic(image);
        setMinHeight(70);

        setGraphicTextGap(10);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);

        setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> {
            is_image_visible_.set(true);
        });

        setOnMouseExited(mouseEvent -> {
            is_image_visible_.set(false);
        });

        image.visibleProperty().bind(is_image_visible_);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            // set back to look of empty cell
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item);
            setGraphic(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)